# License plate recognition scaling problem

Tags: python, opencv

The problem looks like the following, I wrote an algorithm which is supposed to cut the car's license plate from the photo.
Pictures are taken with a camera they are quite large, so I scale them to smaller sizes:

```html
if image is not None:
    scale_percent = 50
     # percent of original size
    width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

From what I noticed there are photos on which the algorithm cannot find the registration and does not cut it, it would not be strange if it were not for the fact that on a 100%, 90%, 80% scale ... it does not work, and if I set the sklae 40% it works.
Other photos work on a 30% scale but not on a 40% scale.

What am I doing wrong or does scaling the photo affect the contours and how to fix it to make it work on every photo

Comment: See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d. Resize does not use pixel dimensions. It uses scale factors (fractions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `cv2.resize(image, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)`

Note: You can consider editing your question tags from java to python.